# Failed to start cpanel-on-almalinux-1-vm

Tags: virtual-machines

I am getting this error while trying to start the instance.

Failed to start cpanel-on-almalinux-1-vm: Operation type [start] failed with message "The resource '276657731774-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com' of type 'serviceAccount' was not found."

It was disabled because of billing issue Which is paid.

How to resolve?

Comment: Have you contacted the host regarding this? If they disabled it due to a billing issue, can you confirm that they have reset the settings now that the billing issue is resolved?